# Creating a Graphic tree with Python, that can also produce larger trees by changing a number that specifies number of levels.

Tags: python

i need help designing a program to create a graphic tree, the lines used for each level should be of Length 10,20 and 30. The program should be able to in principle produce larger trees by simply changing one number that specifies the number of levels. I did something similar with a square design however i am unsure of the numbers to use to turn my square into a tree icon and have them stack on top of each other, similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2x3k.png)

Here is what i have for my Square design

## Draw two squares

```
From turtle import *
```

## draw a square

```
For sides in range (1,5):
forward(40)
right(90)
```

## move to start of next square

```
penup() 
right(90)
forward(50)
left(90)
pendown()
```

## draw a square

```
for sides in range (1,5):
forward(40)
right(90)
```

I am unsure how to turn this into the tree image i linked above, and that can also produce larger trees simply by changing one number that specifies the number of levels.

Thank you

Comment: Start off by drawing a triangle. Now make your turtle draw a triangle, but have it start at the centre of the bottom side and and at the top peak. Now put all that in a loop. Now make the loop variable the tree 'size'.

Comment: I have managed to get it working, i think and by changing my length values it should create bigger and bigger triangles, i have 3 loops for each drawn triangle also. 

Thank you for helping me, i am not sure how to format the comment box correctly so if put my code here it has no spaces or proper formatting and looks pretty bad.

Comment: Glad you've got it working! Well done!

Comment: @Enzo_Dev The code of your solution wouldn't belong into a comment anyway. It's not a comment but (part of) an answer. You are allowed to answer your own questions here. So don't be shy… ☺

Comment: Okay, Thank you for clarity on the commenting issue, this was my first post here lol, i expect i will spend a lot of time here as my course progresses and i begin working in the industry.